# How to pass in the token and Cookie in Taurus

Tags: cookies, yaml, token, performance-testing, taurus

I'm trying to pass in the token and the cookie to my script. When i try to run it with Taurus i get the below error:

ERROR : Config Error: You must specify either a JMX file or list of requests to run JMeter

How do i pass token and cookie in my script?

Here is the script :

```
execution:
- concurrency: 100
  ramp-up: 1m
  hold-for: 2m
  scenario: sample

scenarios:
  sample :
    headers:
      Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp'
      Cookie: 'yourAuthCookie=48DEDbhjbhj08F4A918C1813ADDD9A9C603E4AE1F6648CEA7025CAA676839B72FCE955512C03B86348285307C53385D9C5746BBB8A8F00C6DCCB42A8DAA77DF474F2115B81EEFB3C340B5299A8EF147FC2B9DDE9D488DF96DE3672977D2573A5BCD02C1FDB0A535BBA37FAFF3E4666D'
      token: 'SHIvSkp1TQWswT0Z5WjMwM nvhjvjh1F2NHJWODRUZ3ZPVjcyUGhZQ2ljQ3cyNnFpTFlDaG9UbnRycEE5dDVsd1JmNkdubklISXJhWHgyZkJFS3FUSWtBalE9PQ=='
      requests:
        -'https://www.ericsson.com/umbraco/api/snip/GetUserSessions'
      method: GET
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```
execution:
  - concurrency: 100
    ramp-up: 1m
    hold-for: 2m
    scenario: sample

scenarios:
  sample:
    requests:
      - url: 'https://www.ericsson.com/umbraco/api/snip/GetUserSessions'
        method: GET
        headers:
          Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp'
          Cookie: 'yourAuthCookie=48DEDbhjbhj08F4A918C1813ADDD9A9C603E4AE1F6648CEA7025CAA676839B72FCE955512C03B86348285307C53385D9C5746BBB8A8F00C6DCCB42A8DAA77DF474F2115B81EEFB3C340B5299A8EF147FC2B9DDE9D488DF96DE3672977D2573A5BCD02C1FDB0A535BBA37FAFF3E4666D'
          token: 'SHIvSkp1TQWswT0Z5WjMwM nvhjvjh1F2NHJWODRUZ3ZPVjcyUGhZQ2ljQ3cyNnFpTFlDaG9UbnRycEE5dDVsd1JmNkdubklISXJhWHgyZkJFS3FUSWtBalE9PQ=='
```

When you run `bzt test.yaml -gui` it will result into the following JMeter [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan)

[image]

More information:

- [Taurus - JMeter Executor - Requests](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Requests)
- [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus/)